# nifi how to fix ldap auth?

Tags: ldap, apache-nifi

I have dev instance nifi, I created domain for simple sign in NIFI
When I try to auth, I getting this warn

```
2024-02-21 12:15:33,944 INFO [NiFi Web Server-24] o.a.n.w.a.c.AccessDeniedExceptionMapper identity[test test], groups[] does not have permission to access the requested resource. Unable to view the user interface. Returning Forbidden response.
2024-02-21 12:15:58,244 INFO [NiFi Web Server-25] o.a.n.w.a.c.AccessDeniedExceptionMapper identity[test test], groups[] does not have permission to access the requested resource. Unable to view the user interface. Returning Forbidden response.
2024-02-21 12:15:59,990 INFO [NiFi Web Server-21] o.a.n.w.a.c.AccessDeniedExceptionMapper identity[vskibenko], groups[] does not have permission to access the requested resource. Unable to view the user interface. Returning Forbidden response.
```

my

> nifi.properties

```
(dbt-env) [nifi_adm@esb-app-01 conf]$ cat nifi.properties | grep -v "^#"

nifi.authorizer.configuration.file=./conf/authorizers.xml
nifi.login.identity.provider.configuration.file=./conf/login-identity-providers.xml
nifi.templates.directory=./conf/templates


nifi.web.https.host=0.0.0.0
nifi.web.https.port=8443
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.https.application.protocols=http/1.1
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=/nifi
nifi.web.proxy.host=
nifi.web.max.content.size=
nifi.web.max.requests.per.second=30000
nifi.web.max.access.token.requests.per.second=25
nifi.web.request.timeout=60 secs
nifi.web.request.ip.whitelist=ip
nifi.web.should.send.server.version=true
nifi.web.request.log.format=%{client}a - %u %t "%r" %s %O "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i"

nifi.web.jmx.metrics.allowed.filter.pattern=

nifi.web.https.ciphersuites.include=
nifi.web.https.ciphersuites.exclude=
```

> authorizers.xml

```
(dbt-env) [nifi_adm@esb-app-01 conf]$ cat authorizers.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<authorizers>
    <userGroupProvider>
       <identifier>ldap-user-group-provider</identifier>
       <class>org.apache.nifi.ldap.tenants.LdapUserGroupProvider</class>
       <property name="Authentication Strategy">SIMPLE</property>

       <property name="Manager DN">cn=admin,dc=somedc,dc=com</property>
       <property name="Manager Password">pass</property>

       <property name="TLS - Keystore"></property>
       <property name="TLS - Keystore Password"></property>
       <property name="TLS - Keystore Type"></property>
       <property name="TLS - Truststore"></property>
       <property name="TLS - Truststore Password"></property>
       <property name="TLS - Truststore Type"></property>
       <property name="TLS - Client Auth"></property>
       <property name="TLS - Protocol"></property>
       <property name="TLS - Shutdown Gracefully"></property>

       <property name="Referral Strategy">FOLLOW</property>
       <property name="Connect Timeout">10 secs</property>
       <property name="Read Timeout">10 secs</property>

       <property name="Url">ldap://ip:389</property>
       <property name="Page Size"></property>
       <property name="Sync Interval">30 mins</property>
       <property name="Group Membership - Enforce Case Sensitivity">false</property>

       <property name="User Search Base">ou=nifi,dc=skibenko,dc=ru</property>
       <property name="User Object Class">inetOrgPerson</property>
       <property name="User Search Scope">ONE_LEVEL</property>
       <property name="User Search Filter">(uid={0})</property>
       <property name="User Identity Attribute">uid</property>
       <property name="User Group Name Attribute"></property>
       <property name="User Group Name Attribute - Referenced Group Attribute"></property>

       <property name="Group Search Base"></property>
       <property name="Group Object Class">group</property>
       <property name="Group Search Scope">ONE_LEVEL</property>
       <property name="Group Search Filter"></property>
       <property name="Group Name Attribute"></property>
       <property name="Group Member Attribute"></property>
       <property name="Group Member Attribute - Referenced User Attribute"</property>
    </userGroupProvider>
</authorizers>
```

> login-identity-providers.xml

(dbt-env) [nifi_adm@esb-app-01 conf]$ cat login-identity-providers.xml

```
<provider>
    <identifier>ldap-provider</identifier>
    <class>org.apache.nifi.ldap.LdapProvider</class>
    <property name="Authentication Strategy">SIMPLE</property>
    <property name="Manager DN">cn=admin,dc=somedc,dc=com</property>
    <property name="Manager Password">pass</property>

    <property name="TLS - Keystore"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Keystore Password"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Keystore Type"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Truststore"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Truststore Password"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Truststore Type"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Client Auth"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Protocol"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Shutdown Gracefully"></property>

    <property name="Referral Strategy">FOLLOW</property>
    <property name="Connect Timeout">10 secs</property>
    <property name="Read Timeout">10 secs</property>

    <property name="Url">ldap://ip:389</property>
    <property name="User Search Base">ou=nifi,dc=skibenko,dc=ru</property>
    <property name="User Search Filter">(cn={0})</property>

    <property name="Identity Strategy">USE_USERNAME</property>
    <property name="Authentication Expiration">12 hours</property>
</provider>
```

My domain tree

```
dc=somedc,dc=ru
| ou=nifi (2)
|| nifi_adm (4) 
||| Vladislav Skib (Distinguished Name: cn=Vladislav,ou=nifi_adm,ou=nifi,dc=somedc,dc=com)
|| nifi_users
```

What I seeing every time when try to login in
[image: My nifi logiin page]

How I can promote my ldap users to needed permissions?